# DataProtectorTokenProvider ValidateAsync Always False

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to generate and validate a token with `DataProtectorTokenProvider<TUser>`
I generate the code using GenerateAsync method in POST Action and then use ValidateAsync to validate it in another action PUT

```
public class VerifyPhoneNumberController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
    private readonly DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser> _dataProtectorTokenProvider;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    ...
    
    public VerifyPhoneNumberController(DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser> dataProtectorTokenProvider, 
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        ...
        _dataProtectorTokenProvider = dataProtectorTokenProvider  ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataProtectorTokenProvider));
        _userManager = userManager ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));
        ...
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] PhoneLoginRequest request)
    {
        ...
        var resendToken = await _dataProtectorTokenProvider.GenerateAsync("resend_token", _userManager, user);
        // here token is valid
        var isTokenValid = await _dataProtectorTokenProvider.ValidateAsync("resend_token", resendToken, _userManager, user);
        ...
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody] ResendOtpCodeRequest request)
    {
        ...
        // same token here is invalid
        if (!await _dataProtectorTokenProvider.ValidateAsync("resend_token", request.ResendToken, _userManager, user))
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid resend token");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

However, the response from the ValidateAsync method is always false.

When I generate the code and validate within the same action(POST), it return true.

**Why I can't call method ValidateAsync in a separate request ?**

I debug ValidateAsync method and for somehow it returning false when it tries to compare the userId and actualUserdId

```
var userId = reader.ReadString();
var actualUserId = await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
if (userId != actualUserId)
{
    Logger.UserIdsNotEquals();
    return false;
}
```

[Source:]https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Core/src/DataProtectorTokenProvider.cs

**Am I missing something obvious ?**
It is like the DataProtectorTokenProvider injected in my controller is not keeping data in memory.

Am I getting new instance of DataProtectorTokenProvider per request ?

Comment: Hi, @FolabiAhn, you could [inject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)  `DataProtectorTokenProvider` into controllers. [Data Protection APIs in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: @MichaelWang please check my code, I already inject it

Answer (score 0):

> I debug ValidateAsync method and for somehow it returning false when
> it tries to compare the userId and actualUserdId

Here is the reason why you always get false when excute `if (userId != actualUserId)`.

You should use `userId .Equals(actualUserId)` instead of `==`.

When comparing an object reference to a string (even if the object reference refers to a string), the special behavior of the `==` operator specific to the string class is ignored. If two objects you are comparing are referring to the same exact instance of an object, then both will return true, but if one has the same content and came from a different source (is a separate instance with the same data), **only Equals will return true**.

> Test Codes

```
        string s1 = "test";
        string s2 = "test1".Substring(0, 4);
        object s3 = s2;

        Console.WriteLine("s1  ReferenceEquals s3:     "+ $"{object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s3)}");
        Console.WriteLine("s1  ==              s3:     " + $"{s1 == s3}");
        Console.WriteLine("s1  Equals          s3:     " + $"{s1.Equals(s3)}");
```

> Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is not the problem. There is no problem comparing two Guids with == or !=
The problem comes from my code, I was always generating a new user in my PUT action resulting in a new userId.